# resource not found when using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-17

I have a resource `abc/xyz.json`  under `src/test/resources`. I'm using **IntelliJ** IDE.
While running a *Test* for my project, I get the following exception.

**Exception**

`com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource("abc/xyz.json")`
fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource abc/xyz.json not found.`

The *Test* runs fine with `gradle clean build` and `eclipse`

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Comment: How did you solved your problem with a resource availability?

Answer (score 3):

Try marking your `src/test/resources` folder as Test Resource Root. Attach is the image on how to do it.

[image]

Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: thats strange. can you share your complete piece of code ?

Comment: @skyik did you get the answer of your question?

Answer (score 2):

Make your resource folder a Test Resource folder, if this does not fix the issue then, close your project, delete target folder and open the project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue not that long ago, since Intellij outputs the class files into `out/production/{project_name}`, that path will not start in the `src` directory but will start in the `out/production/{project_name}` directory.

It will however see files that are in the project root directory, I'd recommend moving your resource directory into the main project directory then accessing the file with `"resources\${FILE_NAME}"`.

Comment: I don't think manually copying files to that folder is how intelliJ creators imagined it

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have the same problem, though the folder is marked as resource root. So what I do: I just Unmark it and then mark it as resource root again. Sometimes I need to do it several times and it works. But anyway I think it is Intellij IDEA bug.